# How to highlight div background color as red?

Tags: php, css, laravel

I am using following div in my laravel app and currently I have boarder style now I need color background as red adtype ==1 and other green.

```
<div style="border-style: solid; 
            color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'black' : 'blue' }} ">
    <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250">
</div>
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`color` is for the text, use `background-color` property.

```
background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'red' : 'green' }}
```

Comment: one thing more then how can I change border color as ===1 white and other pink?

Comment: `border-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'white' : 'pink' }}`

Comment: I need border color with above background-color codes

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry

Comment: I mean I need both border style and background-color?

Comment: then combine them both. Instead of just the color print the whole string as a combination, like this `{{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'background-color: red; border-color: white' : 'background-color: green; border-color: pink'}}`

Comment: and you can still keep border-style as it is

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to change your background color:

```
<div style="border-style: solid; color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'black' : 'blue' }}; background-color: {{ $vehicule->adtype === 1 ? 'red' : 'green' }}">
    <img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}" height="150" width="250"></a>
</div>
```